# typo checkのコマンドラインツール

Tags: command-line

AndroidStudioのspellCheckをいつも使うのですが、そのためだけにIDEを起動するのも大変なので、同等のことができるコマンドラインツールなどはないでしょうか。

求める機能としては、

- ブラックリストを登録しないでも動作する
- ホワイトリストを設定できる
- ディレクトリやファイルのinclude/excude設定ができる（これはfindコマンドなどと組み合わせて動くのであれば最悪それでも可）

---

質問としては開発言語を問わないものだと思いますが、私としては直近swiftベースのiosプロジェクトで活かしたいと思っています。

Comment: `aspell -c ファイル名`をまず試してみましょう